# Removing extensions with .htaccess but keeping Parameters causes unstyled page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to build a construct for redirecting or "beautifying" URL.

I would like to achieve following result:

- URL like domain.com/signup.php should be accessed by domain.com/signup
- Paramers should work like domain.com/signup/HASH will lead to domain.com/signup.php?hash=HASH
- If possible multiple parameters should be extendable like domain.com/signup/HASH/VERIFIED -> domain.com/signup.php?hash=HASH&status=verified

My current approach is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA]
```

I tried a lot, but either it doesn't work or it will end in an unstyled page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use absolute links in your pages.**
If you use any graphics or links in your pages, don't use "relative links". Instead, make all your links "absolute links" that start with `http://www.example.com/...`.

Or a root-relative link, beginning the href value with `/`.

In your case: `http://www.example.com/css/Stylesheet.css` or `/css/Stylesheet.css`;

You can also add in the html `<head>`: `<base href="/">`

If you only use parameters at the root of the site, you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# with one parameter
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?hash=$2 [L,NE,QSA]

# with two parameters
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?hash=$2&status=$3 [L,NE,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks! Shame on me. That fixes the styling problem. But the GET parameters are still missing … any idea?

Comment: I added it in my answer

Comment: Thanks so much! You nailed it